# Autosize the last column

Tags: css

I need the last column be autosized, that is, take not more than the max size of the containg elements.

My code ([codepen here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/NaWrWy)) to show the behavior:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    { name: "Milk", ok: true },
    { name: "Bread", ok: true },
    { name: "Cheese", ok: false }
  ];
});

app.directive("toggle", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { ngModel: "=",on:"@", off:"@" },
        template: "<label><input type='checkbox' ng-model='ngModel'>{{ngModel?on:off}}</label>"
    };
});
```

```css
table { width: 100%;  border-collapse: collapse; }
td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td><toggle ng-model="p.ok" on="OK" off="KO"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for I think. The magic happens with CSS:

```
td:last-child {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    { name: "Milk", ok: true },
    { name: "Bread", ok: true },
    { name: "Cheese", ok: false }
  ];
});

app.directive("toggle", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { ngModel: "=",on:"@", off:"@" },
        template: "<label><input type='checkbox' ng-model='ngModel'>{{ngModel?on:off}}</label>"
    };
});
```

```css
table { 
  width: 100%;  
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  resize:both
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow:auto;
}

td:last-child {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td><toggle ng-model="p.ok" on="OKOKOK" off="KO"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make the last `td` and `inline-something` in my example below i made it a `inline-table`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    { name: "Milk", ok: true },
    { name: "Bread", ok: true },
    { name: "Cheese", ok: false }
  ];
});

app.directive("toggle", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { ngModel: "=",on:"@", off:"@" },
        template: "<label title={{ngModel?on:off}}><input type='checkbox' ng-model='ngModel'><span class='slider round'></span>{{ngModel?on:off}}</label>"
    };
});
```

```css
table { width: 100%;  border-collapse: collapse; }
td {border: 1px solid black;}
td:last-of-type{display: inline-table;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td><toggle ng-model="p.ok" on="OK" off="KO"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: all good, but the problem is `tr{background: red;}`, I mean, the other columns are not resiezed accordingly...

Comment: @Sergeyou want all columns to be auto resized? if so just remove the `:last-of-type`

Comment: also, the problem is with `on="OKOKOK" off="KO"`... the last column is broken